# Clarification of python namespaces, specifically between lists and ints

Tags: python, namespaces

I have some experience in C, and having some trouble understanding Python's way of handling names (identifiers). As I understand it, declaring a list `x = [1, 2]` and then declaring a new label `y = x`, I seem to be actually making `x` as the pointer, and `y`, also a pointer, holds the same address as x. But in Python we are calling this labeling (these are different concepts?).

The same system happens with: `x = 5` and `y = x`. Where `x` is now a label for an integer, `5`, and `y` is a label for `5` as well. But now when I change `x` it turns out `y` will not change. So in the latter case, I do not think `x` or `y` are pointers in that sense. Are `x` and `y` on the stack as opposed to the heap? If so, how do I know which one they are? Is applying knowledge of the stack and heap useless in this situation, perhaps even detrimental? I am really confused about this part of the language, thank you for helping.

Comment: This has nothing to do with namespaces.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Sorry then, is there something else I can call it (that would be more constructive)

Comment: Unfortunately not for asking the question.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams If I write "labels" in place of "namespaces" would that be more helpful?

Comment: Maybe "variables", since other languages use those.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yes, but preferably something local to Python users, as those are the individuals I hope can help.

Comment: You probably should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python does not have "pointers", and it does not have "variables", and it does not have "assignment". Instead it **binds** object references to **names**; but we still call the operation performed by the `=` statement "assignment" to simplify things.

When you perform `y = x`, you bind the name `y` to the reference contained in `x` (or vice versa; the distinction is unimportant). The difference in how they are handled depends on the further operations performed upon it.

```
x = []          # A new list object is bound to x
y = x           # The reference bound to x is bound to y as well
x.append(None)  # None is *appended* to the list object bound to `x`
print y         # y is bound to the same list
x = 5           # x is *rebound* to a different object
print y         # y remains bound to the list
```

Comment: The thing confusing me most is why the same thing does not happen for `x = 5` and then `y = x` They are different objects now? Why not for lists? Or is it the `5` that is what cannot be changed, and this is the reason... ah that gives me a headache, maybe I don't need to know.

Comment: @Leonardo No, they are the same object. What is different between `[]` and `5` is that `5` is **immutable**, hence every operation on `5` creates a *new* object, while this isn't true for lists.

Comment: @Bakuriu Ah thank you, for obliterating the confusion that was the part I needed to know!

Comment: @Leonardo: `x = x + [None]` would also create and bind a new object.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yes, but that's not true for `x += [None]`, while `x += 5` *does* create a new object. Reading the question I believe Leonardo found this difference between lists and integers.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams You just brought the headache back.. Why will `x` change and `y` will not, if `y = x` with your example `x += [None]`

Comment: That's dependent on the type of object bound to x though, and not strictly speaking its mutability.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams But when I do `x.append(None)` we have a difference now.. It is because I used a mutator? And you use assignment, which 'creates' new objects.. I think I see it.

Comment: Mutating an object does not rebind it. Rebinding a name does not mutate either object.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams So when `x = x + [None]` occurs, garbage collection deletes the old thing `x` aliased.. I am guessing is what you mean by "Rebinding a name does not mutate either object" That took me a second to process though and I probably do not make much sense, but cant explain it anyway.

Comment: GC does not necessarily happen, but the refcount of the object previously bound to `x` is decremented.